# Buttons not working in Chrome App

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Okay simply i have a packaged app, this app contains index.html and other pages ..
index.html contains buttons Linking to the other pages..

The problem is the buttons is not working !! When I click on the buttons.. nothing happens.

Here's the mainifest file:

```
{
  "name": "TextTools",
  "description": "Simple tools for Text.",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "128": "logo.png"
  },

"app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "index.html"
    }
  }
  }
```

And here is the Index.html body tag :

```
<body>

<center><div id="container">

<div><input id="btn1" type="button" value="Letters Counter" class="btn1" 
onclick="location.href='LettersCounter/LengthCalculator.html';"></div>


<div><input id="btn2" type="button" value="Case Converter"  class="btn2"
onclick="location.href='CaseConverter/CaseConverter.html';"/></input></div>



<div><input type="button" value="Text Capitalizer" class="btn3" 
onclick="location.href='CapitalizeText/CapitalizeText.html';"  /></div>


<div><input type="button" value="Words Counter" class="btn4"
onclick="location.href='WordsCounter/WordsCounter.html';" /></div>


<div><input type="button" value="QR-Generator" class="btn5"
onclick="location.href='QRcode/index.html';"  /></div>


</div></center>


<div id="foot" >

<p style="color:#B8B8B8; margin-left:10px; margin:10px; font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif; font-size : 14px; "></p>
</div>

</body>
```

I know it's very simple but i am new :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

You are using *inline javascript*, which js not allowed by the **[Content Security Policy for Chrome Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html)**:

> The content security policy for Chrome Apps restricts you from doing the following:
>
> - You can’t use inline scripting in your Chrome App pages. The restriction bans both  blocks and event handlers (`<button onclick="...">`).
>
> [...]

---

#### The solution

Use an external `.js` file where you register listeners. E.g.:

```
/* Instead of... */
<input id="btn1" type="button" onclick="..." ... />

/* ...change HTML to... */
<input id="btn1" type="button" ... />
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>

/* ...and in `myScript.js` add... */
document.getElenentById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: @ Khaled: A generally advisable practice, that would have at least told you right away about whatever you were doing wrong, is to look for possible error message in the console -- both for the foreground and background pages of your app, if you can't tell precisely which one you need (and if you don't know how to access the console at all, you should read about that - it's your number one debugging tool). In your particular case, an error message about blocked inline scripts (what ExpertSystem has mentioned) was for sure printed to the console.